# Unused loop variables in Lisp

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp, unused-variables

Sometime, I need to iterate $n$ times where $n$ is the number of elements in a list. Of course, I could write something like:

```
(loop for i from 0 below (list-length l)
      do something)
```

But I like to write rather:

```
(loop for i from 0
      for u in l ; unused 'u' variable
      do something)
```

where the `for u in l` part is merely intended to stop the loop after $n$ iterations. But then I don't use the `u` variable, and the interpreter keeps complaining. Is there some way to handle this style of coding? Should I avoid it and use `list-length` instead?

Comment: Did you consider using `dotimes` or `dolist`?

Comment: Your code is more efficient, but unless your lists are unusually long or this is a critical path, then it's probably premature optimization. The `list-length` version is definitely more clear. To answer the actual question, can you specify which interpreter you're using / care about? Disabling interpreter warnings is likely to be an interpreter-specific technique

Comment: @MartinPůda It is not the same thing; I really need all the power of the `loop` macro for computing sophisticated independent sequences; the whole thing is that I want exactly as many terms as in l.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(loop for i from 0
      for NIL in l
      do something)
```

NIL should do it.

The LOOP destructuring pattern can be empty and the rest list elements are ignored.
Additionally: In a LOOP destructuring pattern, NIL indicates that the variable is not used.

Comment: Thank you for that; this is really what I was asking for! I could have explained my question a little better by referring to the "throwable variable" in other languages (underscore in Python), but you perfectly understood the point.

Comment: This is just a really useful thing to know!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the `repeat` clause:

```
(loop repeat (length l) ...)
```

The argument expression of the `repeat` clause is required to be evaluated once.

Answer (score 0):

One horrible hack to do this which does not involve any extra traversals and if you really need to use `loop` is:

```
(defun foo (l)
  (loop for i upfrom 0
        for u = l then (cdr u)
          while (consp u)
        collect i))
```

But probably Kaz's answer of `(loop repeat (length l) ...)` is fine in practice, if you must use `loop`.